# Add label to flowchart nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I need to add a "label" to nodes in a flowchart with tikz, preferably in the top left corner. See picture: the text in red is where I need it.

This is because each block should have a "label" so I can refer to it elsewhere in the text and in other flowcharts (expanding nodes).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to have any greeting. A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user3822".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the label as second node over the other one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [draw,rounded corners=2pt,fill=blue!20,inner sep=1em] (A)
  {Node content};

\node [anchor=north west,font=\tiny\color{red}] at (A.north west)
  {label};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

There is also the `label` key (see the `pgfmanual` section 16.10 *The Label and Pin Options*, page 194) which exists for adding labels like that. Unfortunately the label can only be on the *outside* of the node. I didn't found out how to place them inside yet. A negative `label distance` seems to have no effect.

```
\node [draw,rounded corners=2pt,fill=blue!20,inner sep=1em,label={[red]north west:\tiny Label outside}] (A)
  {Node content};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly! I actually tried the anchor command, but it did not work :( I must have messed up the arguments? Anyway, now it works, THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 1):

You could overlay the box

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners,draw,fill=blue!30] (a) {Box content}; 
 \node[overlay, xshift=1pt,anchor=north west] at (a.north west) {Label};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That code produces exactly the same output without `overlay`. In fact, the effect of `overlay` is just that everything within the current scope is not taken
into consideration when the bounding box of the current picture is computed (p.199 of the manual).